# extracting task_struct attributes

Tags: struct, process, kernel-module, stat

I'm trying to build a kernal module that can extract attributes of task_struct. I tries the task_struct members [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/ds/ds.html) and the stat members [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). However when I make the module using the `make` command, I got this error for most of the member is,

```
‘struct task_struct’ has no member named ‘priority’
```

here is how I do it:

```
printk(KERN_INFO " process Information:\ncomm: %s \npid: %d \nppid: %d \nstate: %c \nprio: %d \nnice: %ld \npgrp: %d \nutime: %ld \npriority: %d \nprocessor: %d\nvsize: %lu \nrss: %lu \ntext (code): %ld\n", 
                pTask->comm, pTask->pid, pTask->pptr->ppid, pTask->state, pTask->prio, pTask->nice, task_pgrp_vnr(pTask), pTask->utime, pTask->priority, pTask->processor, pTask->Vsize, pTask->rss, pTask->text);
```

Here is the libraries included in my code:

```
#include <linux/module.h> 
#include <linux/kernel.h> 
#include <linux/init.h> 
#include <linux/list.h>     
#include <linux/sched.h> 
#include <linux/cred.h>     
#include <linux/pid.h>
```

Hints? from where I can get these members? what libraries I need to include?

Comment: Linux kernel has no stable API, so API described in the tutorial may differs from API of the kernel you build. See definition of the `struct task_struct` in the header `include/linux/sched.h` in the kernel sources **you have**.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I tried searching for kernel 3.19.0-56-generic, but no use!

Comment: No needs to search kernel headers somewhere, you build your module with using them. Just open corresponded header file in the editor you use,  find definition of the `struct task_struct`, and search member with name like `priority` and appropriate description.